# Is it there a "completely expressive" formal system / logic language?

Tags: logic, epistemology, philosophy-of-logic, computation, formal-theory

I wonder whether it exists a formal system such that all (or a considerable number of) the others can be considered as a subsets or fragments of it.

I would say that, for instance, First-Order logic is a subset of Second-order logic (and so on if we keep with higher-order logics); on the other side, I would argue that, for instance, temporal logics also extend the logics in other directions, adding temporality operators.

So my question is: which is the most expressive logic that you have seen (even if it has no Computation uses, but just philosophical or even recreational) and the most expressive logic that you have seen that actually is used in any application in Computation.

This is obviously not a single answer question (as I use "expressivity" to say just, "what can be said"), just would like you to express what you think.

Comment: There is no "most expressive logic" for the simple reason that already some first order logics are incompatible with each other, e.g. classical, intuitionistic and paraconsistent ones. Already second order logic is not effectively axiomatizable, so of limited computational value, and it gets worse in higher orders, but they get ever more "expressive", and there is no upper bound to that.

Comment: Hello, and welcome. I have to point out that asking for opinions is generally considered [bad practice here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). This one is a bit of a border case, though, since it basically asks for expert experience, which could be seen as on the "good subjective" side. Will leave it to the community to decide upon that :)

Comment: Hey, sorry then, I thought this question's answers can provide interesting knowledge: it can be subjective whether it is the "most expressive or not", but the point is reasoning about arithmetics and so on :)

Comment: Also, for @Conifold: where you say some logics are incompatible with each other, does it mean they cannot be represente by a new logic that contains both (i.e. this union would lead to contradictions)?

Comment: Yes there is a complete formal system. This formal system is the foundation of the body of analytical knowledge. Its entirely comprised of: (1) Expressions of language that are defined to be true and (2) Expressions of language that have been derived on the basis of applying truth preserving operations. The only philosopher that understood this was Ludwig Wittgenstein https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remarks_on_the_Foundations_of_Mathematics Expressions of language such as the liar paradox and Gödel sentence are known to be untrue because their evaluation specifies a directed graph with cycles.

Comment: @polcott I read the link, but I am not sure I understand it completely, could you offer any other source? Thanks a lot, it is really interesting.

Comment: I am the only other source that I am aware of. Everyone else simply believes Gödel. (1) and (2) in the above brief paragraph is the simplest way to make my point. When we get into graphs with cycles this requires an understanding of Minimal Type Theory. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331859461_Minimal_Type_Theory_YACC_BNF

Comment: I will get into it and ask if have any doubt. That "everyone simply believes Gõdel" sound at least like fresh air. Thanks!

Comment: Note that "complete" has a different [technical meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)) than the informal way you use it to mean "expressive". It's easy to find complete logics that aren't all that expressive. In fact completeness in this technical sense is in tension with how expressive a logic is. E.g. 2nd order order logic is incomplete in this technical sense.

Comment: @TheoDeep Firstly, no problem, as I said the question should be fine as-is, just wanted to prepare you for possible close votes or critique ;) Secondly, what polcott tries to advocate historically is called logical positivism, the champions of which can be considered Russel, (early) Wittgenstein, Frege, Husserl (to an extent), and finally Carnap. All of them tried to develop such a complete, yet expressive logic/language, and all of them realised later towards the end of their lives that it is futile. As Fizz correctly points out, expressivity and completeness are antithetical to one another.

Comment: A formal system that is entirely comprised of  (1) Expressions of language that are defined to be true and (2) Expressions of language that have been derived on the basis of applying truth preserving operations can express every element of the entire body of knowledge that can be expressed using language. Any proof that would otherwise show incompleteness in other formal systems cannot be expressed in this formal system. Both the Liar paradox and the Gödel sentence cannot be expressed as truth preserving operations applied to  expressions of language known to be true.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Try and define any incompleteness proof in a formal system that is entirely comprised of (1) Expressions of language that are defined to be true and (2) Expressions of language that have been derived on the basis of applying truth preserving operations. You will find this incompleteness proof is impossible to define. You will also find that such a formal system can represent every element of the body of all knowledge that can be expressed using language.

Comment: @polcott Just stop confusing logical boolean values with pragmatic epistemological truth, would you? All **you** end up with is an idiosyncratic language. You cannot have it both ways: Either you allow for it to be about something outside of it (the world), then it is not a closed system because the fundamental truths are not defined to be true **within**, but **from without** the system. Or you do not, then it may be complete, but idiosyncratic.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking The system that I propose has the scope of all knowledge that can be represented using formal or formalized natural language. The only things that are excluded are direct sensory stimulus from the sense organs. As Richard Montague understood there is nothing that is inherently idiosyncratic about such a system.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Montague, Richard, 1970, “Universal grammar”, Theoria, 36: 373–398. 
Reprinted in Thomason (ed.) 1974, pp. 7–27.
There is in my opinion no important theoretical difference between natural 
languages and the artificial languages of logicians; indeed I consider it possible 
to comprehend the syntax and semantics of both kinds of languages with a 
single natural and mathematically precise theory. (Montague 1970, 373)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no perfectly expressive logic.  Every logic powerful enough to include arithmetic is incomplete.  Moreover, each one of those logics can be augmented by additional axioms to be more complete than it was - to yield more true theorems than it had.  This means that you can always make a logic more complete, so there is no most complete one.

However, there is good news.  Within first-order logic, you can "simulate" the rules of second-order logic and every other logic too.  This is why ZFC (a first-order logic in which the objects are sets) can be considered a foundation for all of mathematics.  What you do is define a proposition in second order logic *as a particular kind of set in ZFC*, and define second-order logic proofs also as particular sets in ZFC, according to rules for how to construct these sets.  Then to ask whether a proposition in second-order logic has a proof, is the same question as whether a particular set exists in ZFC.

Comment: Seems like I have to read more about ZFC, thanks! Indeed I thought that Second-Order logic was the first one providing the quantification over sets, and that First-Order logic did not allow that.

Comment: @TheoDeep: The point is, if you can talk about it meaningfully, it is almost utterly surely that what you are talking about can be expressed in a suitable set theory. It doesn't really matter which set theory, but ZFC is the current conventional foundation for mathematics much for that reason. By the way, polcott is a crank who used sockpuppets (such as "pl_olcott") against SE rules and got suspended on Math SE (until july) for posting nonsense.